# With tkinter, the .get() method doesn't seem to work with my code

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to set up a tkinter window with buttons and labels etc. The button I am adding is meant to call a function, but it isn't working properly.

The function contains the line
x=entry1.get()
But it is saying that entry1 is not defined (although it is defined earlier on in the program).
I'm quite confused as I've seen this work on youtube channels.

This isn't all the code (I've done the root stuff)

```
def game():
    x=entry1.get()
    label=Label(root,textvariable=x)
    label.grid(row=5,column=2)


def mainwindow():

    root=Tk()
    root.title("Typing Game")
    root.geometry("1920x1080")
    entry1=Entry(root)
    entry1.grid(row=2,column=4)
    button=Button(root,text="Hit this button when done",command=game)
    button.grid(row=1,column=4)

    root.mainloop()

mainwindow()
```

X is supposed to end up being the text that they user enters, but its just saying that entry1 is not defined when it tries to execute the line "x=entry1.get()"

Comment: Please post a working code sample so we can reproduce your error. This code that you posted should get an error on line 3, saying that name 'game' is not defined.

Comment: def game():
    x=entry1.get()
    label=Label(root,textvariable=x)
    label.grid(row=5,column=2)


def mainwindow():

    root=Tk()
    root.title("Typing Game")
    root.geometry("1920x1080")
    entry1=Entry(root)
    entry1.grid(row=2,column=4)
    button=Button(root,text="Hit this button when done",command=game)
    button.grid(row=1,column=4)

    root.mainloop()

mainwindow()

Comment: i've updated the posts code

Comment: You are defining `entry1` inside function `mainwindow()` and the variable will be garbage collected when the function ends. So, when the function `game()` tries to call the variable it doesn't exist any more.

Comment: So where do I define entry1?

Answer (score 0):

It is true that `entry1` is not defined at that point. (it is defined later, in the following code). So you need to implement it differently. That would be one way:

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial


def game(entry, label):
    label['text'] = entry.get()


def mainwindow():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Typing Game")
    root.geometry("1920x1080")
    entry1 = Entry(root)
    entry1.grid(row=2, column=4)

    label = Label(root)
    label.grid(row=5, column=2)

    func = partial(game, entry1, label)
    button = Button(root, text="Hit this button when done", command=func)

    button.grid(row=1, column=4)

    root.mainloop()

mainwindow()
```

So I created the label (with no value) in the `mainwindow()` function. In `game(entry, label)` function I just set the value of label. Notice that I changed `game` function to accept 2 parameters so we get rid of the `not defined at tha point` error. Also, I used the `partial` function, so I can assign a function with parameters to the button's command.